# Manufacturer Field Limit?

Tags: magento2, attributes, product-attribute

Can I ask how to increase the number of values that are allowed in the Manufacturer attribute?
We have a store that has well over 250 different brands, which seems to be the limit.

We are using MCE 2.1.2
Seems an odd one, and imagine that many stores have over 250 brands.

Comment: You cannot save more over 100 manufactures options?

Comment: Seems to me he is saying he can't save over 250 manufacture options.  Is this true?

Comment: sorry - it's 250 limit, just wondering if we can make it bigger?

Comment: @CraigDearden Seem that you cannot add more options or cannot save over 250 brands?

Answer (score 1):

Open your `php.ini` file, increase the `max_input_vars`

```
max_input_vars = 10000;
```

Restart your web service and try again.

Comment: This fix the problem for me. However, I have to reach out to the host provider to modify php.ini due to how the site is hosted, so the person who makes the change need to know how their php.ini works as well.